# Подменить EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

Есть слой DAO в котором EntityManager;
Есть две конфигурации для работы с БД (тестовая версия поднимается просто в памяти). В интеграционных тестах добавлена конфигурация тестового подключения. Может кто подсказать как сделать что-бы при запуске тестов, которые обращаются к раестам контроллера, EntityManager в DAO слое подменялся на тот который прописан в тестовой конфигурации.

Добавил в архиве проект [скачать Example.7z](https:////transfiles.ru/8ssfg) Мне надо чтоб тестах DAO работал с hsqldb, но он все равно работает с postgresql. Спасибо

```
 @Repository
 public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {
     private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDAOImpl.class);

     @PersistenceContext
     private EntityManager entityManager;
     /----/
 }




 @WebAppConfiguration
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
 @ContextConfiguration(classes = {DBTestConfiguration.class})
 public class UserControllerIntegrationTest {
     private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserControllerIntegrationTest.class);

     private MockMvc mockMvc;

     private static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/";

     @Autowired
     private RestTemplate restTemplate;

     @Autowired
     ObjectMapper mapper;

     @Mock
     private UserDAO userDAO;

     @Before
     public void init(){
         MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
         mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                 .standaloneSetup(userDAO)
                 .build();
     }
     /----/
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

У тебя довольно странная конфигурация:

```
@Mock
private UserDAO userDAO;
```

+

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

Получается что ты создаешь свой `UserDAO` не средствами **Spring**, а средствами **Mockito**

Далее:

```
mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                 .standaloneSetup(userDAO)
                 .build();
```

Почему в параметрах `userDAO`, а не объект-контроллер?

Теперь по сути.

Если у тебя есть тестовая конфигурация (предположительно в `DBTestConfiguration`), то бины в ней следует пометить как [@Primary](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html). У тебя должно быть что-то подобное:

```
@Configuration 
public class DBTestConfiguration {

    .....


    @Bean
    @Primary
    public EntityManager entityManager(){
    .....
    }


    .....
}
```

Теперь к созданию mock-контроллера. Тут у каждого свой путь. К примеру, я использую создание через слой **Spring** без **Mockito**. Применительно к тебе это будет как-то так:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
 @ContextConfiguration(classes = {DBTestConfiguration.class})
 public class UserControllerIntegrationTest {
     private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserControllerIntegrationTest.class);

     private MockMvc mockMvc;

     private static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/";

     @Autowired
     private RestTemplate restTemplate;

     @Autowired
     ObjectMapper mapper;

     @Autowired
     ApplicationContext applicationContext;

     @Before
     public void init(){
         Class clazz = MyRestController.class; // тут используй свой класс
         Object controller = applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().createBean(clazz); 
         mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                 .standaloneSetup(controller)
                 .build();
     }
     /----/
 }
```

Comment: @hmeli7 тут нужно больше информации, чтобы разобраться